ESP32-WROOM-32UE cannot be powered and loaded with firmware
I designed a custom ESP32 board (schematic attached). I am using an ESP32-WROOM-32UE. My schematic is based on the ESP32-Devkitc-V4 board from Espressif (schematic attached).
When I connect the board to a 5V battery, the 5V connector does not power me, and when I try to load a program via USB and the Arduino does not identify it, I downloaded the Uart - Usb driver but the error continues.
Operating System: Windows 10 Board: Custom (based on ESP32-Devkitc-V4 from Espressif) IDE: Arduino Bridge
My schematic

ESP32-Devkitc-V4 board from Espressif schematic

--

What do you mean by "the 5V connector does not power me"? What is not powered? And how did you determine it?

I also note that the reset circuit is probably not correct. For one of the transistors, collector and emitter are swapped.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Good morning,
Thanks for responding, the connector I am referring to is a jack for a 3.7V lipo battery (CN1) to power the esp32, I added it in the Connector session but I am not sure if it is correctly installed. You are right, a transistor was bad for me.
